# how to combine array in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [order_id] => 1
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [photographer_id] => 3
                    [attributes_id] => 2,3
                    [product_type] => 0
                    [status] => pending
                    [is_deleted] => 0
                    [created_at] => 2016-05-15 04:08:21
                    [updated_at] => 2016-05-16 12:11:23
                    [username] => user
                    [photographer] => photographer
                    [product_name] => sdf
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [order_id] => 1
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [photographer_id] => 3
                    [attributes_id] => 1,3
                    [product_type] => 1
                    [status] => pending
                    [is_deleted] => 0
                    [created_at] => 2016-05-15 04:08:21
                    [updated_at] => 2016-05-16 12:11:23
                    [username] => user
                    [photographer] => photographer
                    [product_name] => qqqqqqqqqq
                )

            [attributesValue] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Attributes 2, Attributes 3
                    [1] => Attributes 1, Attributes 3
                )
        )
)
```

I want this array in (see, I added one key name attributes)

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [order_id] => 1
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [photographer_id] => 3
                    [attributes_id] => 2,3
                    [product_type] => 0
                    [status] => pending
                    [is_deleted] => 0
                    [created_at] => 2016-05-15 04:08:21
                    [updated_at] => 2016-05-16 12:11:23
                    [username] => user
                    [photographer] => photographer
                    [product_name] => sdf
                    [attributes] => Attributes 2, Attributes 3
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [order_id] => 1
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [photographer_id] => 3
                    [attributes_id] => 1,3
                    [product_type] => 1
                    [status] => pending
                    [is_deleted] => 0
                    [created_at] => 2016-05-15 04:08:21
                    [updated_at] => 2016-05-16 12:11:23
                    [username] => user
                    [photographer] => photographer
                    [product_name] => qqqqqqqqqq
                    [attributes] => Attributes 1, Attributes 3
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Can you post your actual array ?

Comment: Not a clear question...

Comment: Please specify the behaviour you want to achieve. From the context one can assume that you want to match each entry in `attributesValue` with each entry in `items` excluding `attributesValue` but its not clear whether this is the case.

Comment: Got you, check my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I am assume your array shouild be like this.

```
<?php
$your_arr = array(
    'items' => array(
        array(
            'id' => '1',
            'order_id' => '1',
            'product_id' => '1',
            'user_id' => '2',
            'photographer_id' => '3',
            'attributes_id' => '2,3',
            'product_type' => '0',
            'status' => 'pending',
            'is_deleted' => '0',
            'created_at' => '2016-05-15 04:08:21',
            'updated_at' => '2016-05-16 12:11:23',
            'username' => 'user',
            'photographer' => 'photographer',
            'product_name' => 'sdf' ,   
        ),
        array(
            'id' => '1',
            'order_id' => '1',
            'product_id' => '1',
            'user_id' => '2',
            'photographer_id' => '3',
            'attributes_id' => '2,3',
            'product_type' => '0',
            'status' => 'pending',
            'is_deleted' => '0',
            'created_at' => '2016-05-15 04:08:21',
            'updated_at' => '2016-05-16 12:11:23',
            'username' => 'user',
            'photographer' => 'photographer',
            'product_name' => 'sdf' ,
        ),
        'attributesValue' => array(
             0 => 'Attributes 2, Attributes 3'
             1 => 'Attributes 1, Attributes 3'
        )
    )
);
```

The idea is loop over your items then check 
if their is attributesValue is exits according to current key, then assign into new node 'attributes'

```
<?php
    $new_arr = array();
    foreach($your_arr as $key => $item) {
        $new_arr[$key] = $item;
        if(isset($your_arr['attributesValue'][$key])) {
            $new_arr[$key]['attributes'] = $your_arr['attributesValue'][$key];
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($new_arr);
    ?>
```

Comment: I think the looping should go over `$your_arr["items"]` and ignore the 'attributeValues' key.

Comment: Nice, What about my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example of what (I think) is the behaviour you want to achieve:

The idea is to separate the attribute values out of the array and match the indices in this array with the indices in the `items` subarray of your array.

```
<?php
$arr = [
    "items" => [
        (object)[ "id"=> 1 ],
        (object)[ "id"=> 2 ],
        "attributeValues" => [
            "Attribute for id 1",
            "Attribute for id 2"
        ]
    ]    
];
$attributes = $arr["items"]["attributeValues"];
unset($arr["items"]["attributeValues"]);

foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($arr["items"][$key])) {
        $arr["items"][$key]->attributes = $value;
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

Prints:

```
Array 
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [attributes] => Attribute for id 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [attributes] => Attribute for id 2
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Nice, What about my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should work, if not then let me know. Let your array name is $arr. First store your `attributesValue` from `$arr` and unset it from the main array. Now loop the array and add the new `attributes` in the array, use `&` for the reference so the main array also changed.

Check Online: https://3v4l.org/mJJR4, Thanks to @RanjeetSingh for the array.

```
$arr = array(
    'items' => array(
        array(
            'id' => '1',
            'order_id' => '1',
            'product_id' => '1',
            'user_id' => '2',
            'photographer_id' => '3',
            'attributes_id' => '2,3',
            'product_type' => '0',
            'status' => 'pending',
            'is_deleted' => '0',
            'created_at' => '2016-05-15 04:08:21',
            'updated_at' => '2016-05-16 12:11:23',
            'username' => 'user',
            'photographer' => 'photographer',
            'product_name' => 'sdf' ,   
        ),
        array(
            'id' => '1',
            'order_id' => '1',
            'product_id' => '1',
            'user_id' => '2',
            'photographer_id' => '3',
            'attributes_id' => '2,3',
            'product_type' => '0',
            'status' => 'pending',
            'is_deleted' => '0',
            'created_at' => '2016-05-15 04:08:21',
            'updated_at' => '2016-05-16 12:11:23',
            'username' => 'user',
            'photographer' => 'photographer',
            'product_name' => 'sdf' ,
        ),
        'attributesValue' => array(
             'Attributes 2, Attributes 3',
             'Attributes 1, Attributes 3'
        )
    )
);

$attribute = $arr['items']['attributesValue'];
unset($arr['items']['attributesValue']);

foreach($arr['items'] as $key => &$values){
    $values['attributes'] = $attribute[$key];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_attr($items, $attr) {
    $items->attributesValue = $attr;
    return $items;
}

$attribute = $items['attributesValue'];
unset($items['attributesValue']);
$new_array = array_map(add_attr, $items, $attribute);

print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider adding some explanation to your code. Thank you!

Comment: @Aurasphere Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

use this code, it is helpful to you :)

```
$var = array();

    foreach($array['items'] as $k => $v)
    {
        $var[$k] = $v;
        $var[$k]['attributesValue'] = $array['items']['attributesValue'][$k];

    }

    unset($var['attributesValue']);

print_r($var);
```